# "conda" command returns "failed to start process" after updating Continuum Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, powershell, anaconda, conda

I had a working version of Anaconda 2.3 on my Windows 10 PC. (I use PowerShell as my preferred command line interface.)

After updating to Anaconda 2.4, any command using `conda` or `anaconda` resulted in the message `failed to start process`.

I tried and uninstalling, redownloading and reinstalling, and even tried reverting to 2.3. Nothing worked!

Answer (score 3):

Starting to get desperate, I eventually found the solution: I used `python` to run the script `conda-script.py`, which is apparently what the command `conda.exe` runs when called:

```
python PATH_TO_ANACONDA\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py
```

(Here, I'm using `PATH_TO_ANACONDA` to represent the directory in which the **Anaconda3** folder resides on my particular system.)

Thereafter, both `conda` and `anaconda` commands work perfectly, and continue to work. (e.g. No need to repeat the process every time I launch PowerShell.). But I have no idea why the problem occurred, or why that happened to be the solution.

If you know, please reply. If not, I just hope this solution saves others an hour or so of frustration.